# Set the DATA_DEFAULT value for a table column in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In Oracle SQL Developer, how does one set the default value for a column on a table definition?

(In SQL Developer 3.2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the 'Connections' tab, right-click on a table in your database, and click 'Edit' from the context menu.

A window like this will appear:

[image: Edit Table window]

Select the column that you wish to set a default value, then from the 'Column Properties' panel you can set the default value by populating the 'Default:' field in the form.

After selecting 'OK', the table definition will list the value in the 'DATA_DEFAULT' value in the table definition.

This can also be achieved in the DDL (Data Definition Language) by using the 'DEFAULT' keyword when defining the column, like this:

```
"ATTACH_FROM" CHAR(1 CHAR) DEFAULT 'S'
```

Comment: I cannot find this connections tab that you mention, nor an interface like the image. Does the oracle sql developer data modeler has changed its interface that much ?

Comment: I was using Oracle SQL Developer 11g, I hadn't thought it had changed much!

Comment: Hi, How if I want to set date type with current date? I use Oracle SQL Developer v4.1

Answer (score 1):

Run the DDL from the SQL editor:

```
alter table TABLE_NAME modify COLUMN_NAME default VALUE;
```